# How do I overlay two different 3d plots in manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have two different 3D Plots that I what to be overlayed and manipulated at the same time. Specifically:

```
p1 = Manipulate[
  ContourPlot3D[
   1 - a11 P - a12 B - a13 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], 
   Mesh -> None], {{a11, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a12, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a13, 1}, 0, 2}]
p2 = Manipulate[
  ContourPlot3D[
   1 - a21 P - a22 B - a23 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], 
   Mesh -> None], {{a21, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a22, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a23, 1}, 0, 2}]
```

Without manipulate I can overlay them easily

```
p1 = ContourPlot3D[
   1 - 0.5 P - 1.2 B - 0.5 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], Mesh -> None];
p2 = ContourPlot3D[
   1 - P - 0.3 B - 0.1 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], Mesh -> None];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

How can I do the same but with manipulate?

**Notes**

- If you need clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: `Manipulate[Show[{
   ContourPlot3D[
    1 - a11 P - a12 B - a13 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], Mesh -> None],
   ContourPlot3D[
    1 - a21 P - a22 B - a23 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], Mesh -> None]
   }],
 {{a11, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a12, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a13, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a21, 1}, 0, 
  2}, {{a22, 1}, 0, 2}, {{a23, 1}, 0, 2}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one Manipulate

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{p1, p2, i, B, p},
  p1 = ContourPlot3D[
    1 - a11 P - a12 B - a13 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], Mesh -> None
    ];
  p2 = ContourPlot3D[
    1 - a21 P - a22 B - a23 i == 0, {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown], Mesh -> None
    ];
  Show[p1, p2]
  ],
 {{a11, 1}, 0, 2},
 {{a12, 1}, 0, 2},
 {{a13, 1}, 0, 2},
 {{a21, 1}, 0, 2},
 {{a22, 1}, 0, 2},
 {{a23, 1}, 0, 2},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23}
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a single `ContourPlot` using `Evaluate[1 - {{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}}.{P, B, i}]` as the first argument:

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[1 - {{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}}.{P, B, i}], 
   {P, 0, 1}, {B, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> (Opacity[0.5, #] & /@ {Brown, Blue}), 
   Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {2.5, 1, 2}], 
 Grid[Transpose@
    {{Control@{{a11, .5}, 0, 2}, Control@{{a12, 1.2}, 0, 2}, Control@{{a13, .5}, 0, 2}}, 
     {Control@{{a21, 1}, 0, 2}, Control@{{a22, .3}, 0, 2}, Control@{{a23, .1}, 0, 2}}}], 
 TrackedSymbols :> {a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]